# angularjs，I'm using ng-repeat loop option,value="number:1"

Tags: angularjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AZkP.jpg)

This situation causes the form submission parameter to become “number:1”。
Could you tell me why this problem happened?

javascript code as follows:

```
app.controller("Controller", function($scope,$http,$filter){
   $http({
        method:"POST",
        url:"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/user.getUser",
        params:{"name":name}
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert("00");
    });
   $http({
        method:"POST",
        url:"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/group.selectAll"
    }).then(function successCallback(res) {
        if(res != null && res != ""){
            $scope.userGroups = res.data;
        }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert("00");
    });
 }
```

jsp code as follows:

```
 <select name="positionId" class="form-control"
            ng-model="data.userGroup.GroupId" >
        <option ng-repeat="p in userGroups" value="p.GroupId"
                ng-value="{{p.GroupId}}">{{p.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Please Add some code or see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: not getting your question..could you please add some code

Comment: jsp代码：<select name =“groupId”class =“form-control”ng-model =“data.userGroup.groupId”> <option ng-repeat =“u in userGroups”value =“u.groupId”ng-value =“{{u.groupId}}”> {{u.name}} </ option> </ select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.controller("Controller", function($scope,$http,$filter){
   var userGroups={};
   $http({
        method:"POST",
        url:"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/group.selectAll"
    }).then(function successCallback(res) {
        if(res != null && res != ""){
            $scope.userGroups = res.data;
        }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert("00");
    });

   $http({
        method:"POST",
        url:"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/user.getUser",
        params:{"name":name}
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        //$scope.data = response.data;
        $scope.userGroups.GroupId = "" + response.GroupId;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert("00");
    });
 }
```

After getting the values in the JS controller file, write dropdown list in the view page as below:

```
<select name="positionId" class="form-control"
            ng-model="userGroups.GroupId" >
        <option ng-repeat="p in userGroups" value={{p.GroupId}}>
           {{p.name}}
        </option>
 </select>
```

If you want to set a particular value in a dropdown list to show while loading the dropdown then simply assign the value to the ng-model in the respective js controller file as below:

```
$scope.userGroups.GroupId = "" + response.GroupId; // based on your specific  data
```

(Note: please check I have set ng-model as userGroups.GroupId and assigned `userGroups={};` to initialize the userGroups to be used in the view page.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.js"></script>

</head>

<body data-ng-app="role" data-ng-controller="fooController">
  <select class="form-control" 
    ng-model="user.roles"
    ng-options="role.id as role.name for role in roles" 
    required=""></select>
</body>

</html> 

<script>
var app = angular.module('role', []);

app.controller('fooController', function($scope){
$scope.roles = [{id:0, name:"Select"},{id:1, name:"Administrator"}, {id:2, name: "Student"}];
$scope.user = {};
$scope.groupId = 1;
$scope.user.roles = $scope.roles[$scope.groupId].id ;
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can solve.but   I want to select automatically based on the NG-MODEL value.You modified the value of ng-model, you can't choose it automatically

Comment: Updated my answer. Can you please explain a bit more so that I can get your problem statement

Comment: English is not very good，Server response data.userGroup.GroupId=1，     Server response userGroup：[{GroupId:1，name:Engineer}，{GroupId:2，name:doctor}]。

Comment: according to  data.userGroup.GroupId=1                                                   select         {GroupId:1，name:Engineer}

Comment: Web refresh default selection   data.userGroup.GroupId=userGroups.GroupId     


That one option

Comment: Where data.userGroup.GroupId=1 is assigned??